# PHP MYSQL Update multiple fields including DATETIME field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I can update the field 'delivered' from 0 to 1 no problem but when I try to update 'delivered_time' nothing happens in the database. This may be to do with the way I am writing the code but If anybody could help I would really appreciate it, thanks!

```
if (isset($_POST['delivered']) === false) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `listings` SET `delivered_time` = '{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}' AND `delivered` = 1 WHERE `order_id` = $order_id");
}
```

I have also tried this but this did not work either

```
if (isset($_POST['delivered']) === false) {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `listings` SET `delivered_time` = NOW() AND `delivered` = 1 WHERE `order_id` = $order_id");
}
```

My MYSQL database is set to have 'delivered' defined to 0 and is stored as an INT value. The 'delivered_time' field is stored as a DATETIME value in the database.

Comment: You can't use `AND`when using `SET`, you have to use comas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delivered']) === false) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `listings` SET `delivered_time` = NOW(),`delivered` = 1 WHERE `order_id` = ".$order_id);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`,` not `AND` as the field separator; `AND` is used in WHERE clauses

```
UPDATE `listings` 
   SET `delivered_time` = '{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}',
       `delivered` = 1 
 WHERE `order_id` = $order_id
```